# Box.Net iOS SDK Moving Files and Folders

Tags: ios, sdk, box-api

I am currently developing an iOS application and am implementing the Box.Net SDK. I have gotten everything to work except the ability to move files around, which is not a native feature of the SDK. I am trying to twist my way through it.

If you are familiar with the structure of Box.Net, each file/folder has an ID number for itself, and an ID its parent. From what I understand if I want to move a file, I am supposed to change the parent ID number on the file which will point it to the new location. I can't seem to get it to work properly though. My application seems to keep crashing.

This is what I have so far, generalized.

```
BoxObject *boxObject = [[[Box objectWithID:(ID#ofParent)] children] objectAtIndex:i];
[boxObject parent].boxID = 0; // <-- Problem (causes crash)
```

I also tried this.

```
[boxObject setParent:[Box folderWithID:[BoxID numberWithInt:i]]];
```

The boxObject variable is the file that I want to move. I am setting its parent ID equal to 0, which is supposed to be the root folder. However, my application crashes when I try to reassign the parent ID for the file. Any ideas on how to successfully move files/folders? Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I suppose there wasn't a way to do fix this in-house with the SDK. So, I had to send out an external PUT request. I used the following code to handle moving files.

```
- (void)moveItem:(BoxObject *)object toParentFolderWithID:(BoxID *)parentID
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/files/%@", object.boxID]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *auth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BoxAuth api_key=%@&auth_token=%@",[Box boxAPIKey],[defaults objectForKey:@"box-api-auth-token"]];

NSString *payload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"parent\": {\"id\": %@}}", parentID];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSMutableData dataWithData:[payload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
[request setValue:auth forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
}
```

Just as a reminder if you are new to the Box SDK, you will most likely need to update/refresh the data after moving the files. If not handled, your application could crash if the file doesn't exist. Hope this helps to anyone was not sure about this.